# Can't install sublime or anything! on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, python3

> sudo apt-get install sublime-text

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apport : Depends: python3-apport (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.16) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15 is to be installed
 apport-gtk : Depends: python3-apport (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.16) but 2.20.1-0ubuntu2.15 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Have you resolved the dependencies before trying it again?

Comment: No there are broken dependencies.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`?